# Why is there a huge clickable gap in between my logo and my navigation bar and how to get rid of it?

Tags: html, css, image, web

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-links,
.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.logo {
  max-width: 80%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}

.navbar img {
width: 10%;
height: auto;
display: in-line block;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 50vh;
}

.navbar,
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

ul li {
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/714128376884887644/783384657366482954/Double20Hospital20Doors20push20plate20and20kickplate.png" alt=""></a>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">About Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="ul2">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Above is my code, as you can see there's a huge gap in between my image and the above highlighted below:

[image]

It also seems like the white space in between it is clickable. I want to get rid of it so it looks like this instead (keeping the spacing in between about us and contact us but removing the spacing between the image and Home):

[image]

I tried getting rid of all padding and changing my logo to inside my unorder list, but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For best results, set image size by height, ex:

```
img {
   height: 30px;
   width: auto;
}
```

See the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8hdt4rfu/1/

Comment: for some reason this works in my codepen but not my editor's live server. weird

Comment: How does it look in your editor's live server? Inspect the extra unnecessary CSS that your code may have because that must be the reason you don't have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the width of the Image to a set amount of pixels and not a percent like so:

```css
.navbar img {
width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it reduced the gap but the gap is still there even when I make my width like 1pixel, any idea how to get rid of that gap so I can adjust the space in-between the logo and 'home'?

Comment: Add a second class to Home and set the CSS of it to something like "margin-left: 10px" @JohnnyRobertson

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to target a class by the name of logo in your CSS file, but when I look at your HTML, I don't see a class='logo'.

Comment: He doesn't need to reference logo when he is referencing all tags of "IMG" in "navbar".

Answer (score 0):

In response to his request in the comments, here is the final code snippet:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-links,
.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.logo {
  max-width: 80%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}

.navbar img {
width: 10%;
height: auto;
display: in-line block;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 50vh;
}

.navbar,
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

ul li {
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-logo{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/714128376884887644/783384657366482954/Double20Hospital20Doors20push20plate20and20kickplate.png" alt=""></a>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links nav-logo">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">About Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="ul2">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to make the image 10% inside `<a>` tag, it means that the difference between `<a>` tag and `<img>` tag must be 90%, that's how I understand that. So you can solve your issue just by changing % to pixels, or change percentage on `<a>` and `<img>` tags.

```
.navbar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: in-line block;
}

.navbar a {
  width: 10%;
}
```

But as i can see you mixed up everything in your html/css, you can achieve the same result by this way:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.leftbar, .rightbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40%;
}

.rightbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 16%;
}

.navbar img {
  width: 100%
}

.navbar a {
  width: 20%;
}

.nav-links {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="leftbar">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/714128376884887644/783384657366482954/Double20Hospital20Doors20push20plate20and20kickplate.png" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-links">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-links">Products</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-links">About&nbsp;Us</a>
  </div>
  <div class="rightbar">
    <a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact&nbsp;Us</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-links">Blog</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```